# use HttpServletRequest in my Spring MVC application? Any benefits?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I came across authentication code in my company's java code. The application is a set of several REST services built on Spring MVC. There is a method that gets called in one of the authentication services on the HttpServletRequest object called getHeader(). And the method retrieves an AuthId. Why would they use HttpServletRequest in a spring MVC application? What are the benefits of using this servlet type code in the spring app? What would this method do? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC is built on the `Servlet` API. Anything you could do with a `Servlet`, you can therefore do with Spring MVC. What the Spring MVC framework provides is a wrapper to code a web application in a specific architectural style. This wrapper adds behavior and some times simplifies tasks.

> Why would they use HttpServletRequest in a spring MVC application?

In this case, because it is the most direct way to get the header.

> What are the benefits of using this servlet type code in the spring
>   app?

Spring doesn't have to wrap anything. You get it directly from the source.

> What would this method do?

[Read the javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29)

> Any alternatives?

In a [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) class' handler method, you can declare a parameter annotated with [`@RequestHeader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) and have Spring pass an argument that it retrieves from the `HttpServletRequest` headers.

This is, by default, restricted to `@Controller` methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. If your service class is a `HandlerInterceptor`, `Filter`, or other type of class and simply has a reference to the `HttpServletRequest` object, there is nothing more you can do than retrieve it directly with `getHeader(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC provides a lot of fabulous abstractions on top of `HttpServletRequest`, so you can avoid its low-level implementation details. You rarely need to access it directly.

For example, you could get a header value like `Content-Type` like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/myService")
public Response doSomething(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType) {
...
}
```

But there are times when you do need to access the `HttpServletRequest` directly--usually when you are using another API that demands it. If you are using some other library with a method you need that takes `HttpServletRequest`, then you got to grab it from Spring MVC directly.

For example, check out this method in this random `UrlUtil` [class](https://code.google.com/p/springblog-by-hand/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/prospring3/web/util/UrlUtil.java?r=5):

```
public static String encodeUrlPathSegment(String pathSegment, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
//Get a path segment
}
```

You have no choice but to grab `HttpServletRequest` from Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative : Spring MVC define the parameter annotation `@RequestHeader` to read httpServletRequest headers :

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public @ResponseBody String myMethod(@RequestHeader String AuthId){
    //the value of the parameter AuthId is the value of request header named AuthId
    ...
}
```